# Create a random door in pygame

Tags: python, random, pygame

I am trying to create a random door in pygame. I have a created a wall structure as such:

```
level = [
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W              WWWWWWWWW                W",
"               W       W                 ",
"W              W       W                W",
"W              W       W                W",
"W              W       W                W",
"W              WWWWWWWWW                W",
"                                         ",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]
```

The image looks like this:
[image]

I would like to create a random door in the rectangle in the centre. A person is fixed inside the rectangle in the centre. So he has to try to get out of the random door.

Need some ideas on how to create a random door. Any suggestion is welcome. Better method of implementing is also welcome.

Code:

```
class Wall(object):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)

level = [
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W              WWWWWWWWW                W",
"               W       W                 ",
"W              W       W                W",
"W              W       W                W",
"W              W       W                W",
"W              WWWWWWWWW                W",
"                                         ",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]

x = y = 0
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "W":
            Wall((x, y))
        x += 16
    y += 16
    x = 0
for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), wall.rect)
```

Comment: What _exactly_ is your problem? Obtaining a random coordinate for the door should not be too difficult using `random.randrange` (draw random number for x between x_min and x_max, then do the same for y [don't forget to exclude the corners] and put it in).

Comment: My problem is how to create the random door? This is because I thought I need to edit the level variable. How do you find the x_min and x_max? can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I haven't really used `pygame` for more than some tutorial stuff. It would help if you could post your complete code or link to it. I can help you with getting a random coordinate where you can then put the door. But without any further code I can not help you with the _how_ of placing the door (and getting it to work, i.e. opening / closing, etc.).

Comment: posted the code.. have a look..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your `level` to something that denotes walls that can become a random door. I've chosen "R" to denote walls that have a possibility of being a random door.

```
level = [
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W              WRRRRRRRW                W",
"               R       R                 ",
"W              R       R                W",
"W              R       R                W",
"W              R       R                W",
"W              WRRRRRRRW                W",
"                                         ",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"W                                       W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]
```

I've also created a function called `RandomDoorCreator`, which accepts a `level`, and alters the `level` to include a random "door" -- it really just replaces a random location with ' '.

```
import random
def RandomDoorCreator(level):
    locationsfordoor = []
    xpos = ypos = 0
    for element in level:
        ypos=0
        for letter in element:
            if letter == 'R':
                locationsfordoor.append([xpos,ypos]) #If it's a possible door location, add it to the list of possibilities
            ypos+=1
        xpos+=1
    doorlocation = random.choice(locationsfordoor) #Pick a random location from our list of locations
    newrow = list(level[doorlocation[0]]) #Create a list of strings for the row that we want to replace
    newrow[doorlocation[1]] = ' ' #Replace the correct value in the row with ' '
    del(level[doorlocation[0]]) #Delete the old row from the level
    level.insert(doorlocation[0],''.join(newrow)) #Add the new row to the level
```

Then later, you'd have to edit your `for` loop to account for the new "R"s:

```
RandomDoorCreator(level) #Create a random door BEFORE we create walls
x = y = 0
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "W" or col == "R": #Only row changed -- we just want to account for our new R values
            Wall((x, y))
        x += 16
    y += 16
    x = 0
for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), wall.rect)
```

The reason that I like this method is that you can create multiple levels which are completely different, and still pass it to the function without any additional code. It also makes it visually easy to choose possible randomized door locations which I think can aid in the production of the game.

Comment: Hi @rwflash. First of all, thanks for the code. Just one more qn. Your code randomizes the door. However if I was to randomize the door during the game itself, how would I do that?